# Как с помощью vue-cli создать несколько страниц?

Tags: vue.js, spa, vue-cli

Создаю приложение на vue-cli, и мне нужно добавить в DOM несколько новых страниц. Я так понимаю, что на vue это невозможно, так как это SinglePageApplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждая станица в `vue` - это компонент, в который подключаются другие компоненты.

Для перехода по страницам нужен будет `vue-router` https://router.vuejs.org/ru/ *(примеров работы с `vue-router` в сети полно)*